# android testcase execution from Eclipse vs. console remote instrumentation

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Given an Android project in Eclipse build from 2 projects:
Project 1 is a Java library, which compiles just fine on Android.
Project 2 are test cases for the library, essentially classes extending `AndroidTestCase` and outputting results to the Android console.
Project 1 is a Java project, Project 2 is an Android project depending on Project 1.

Problem Description: If I execute the tests from Eclipse as Android JUnit Tests they run just as they should, no errors. However, if I want to execute them again by commandline:

`adb shell am instrument -w bla.bla/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner`

I get a lot of

```
Cannot load class. Make sure it is in your apk. Class name: xyz
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: xyz
     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:234)
     at android.test.ClassPathPackageInfoSource.createPackageInfo
     ....

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: xyz in loader
     dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar:/data/app/bla.apk]
     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
     ....
```

errors in logcat.

Observations:
Eclipse installs the .apk.
Later I execute the same already installed .apk, so the classes available must be the same.
Classes are dynamically requested with `Class c = Class.forName("xyz")`.

So my the question is, how does Eclipse execute the installed .apk differently so that the proper classes are found at runtime?

Comment: Can I suggest a better way to test your Android application? I use this and it's great: http://pivotal.github.com/robolectric/. No emulator, no separate testing project... and I can do TDD, iterating quickly.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure xyz.class is in CLASSPATH?

I had the same problem and was just this!